# Git Submodule Still Showing after Deinit

Tags: git, github

I took the following steps to completely remove my submodules: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule/36593218#36593218)

Everything is gone, but the really annoying thing is that when I view the repository on Github, it's still showing the module, but its grayed out. Is there a way to get rid of it? It's just super annoying to see that it's there, when it's really not...

I have:

- Removed the submodule entry from `.git/config`
- Removed the submodule directory from `.git/modules`
- Removed the entry from `.gitmodules`

Github recognizes that it has been removed, but it still shows it on Github as a grayed out Submodule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - No, I've already removed it. After it was removed, it still shows on Github as a grayed out submodule and it's just bothering me.

Comment: So you completely removed it from history?  I don't see how GitHub could be picking up on it if you had done so.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah that's what I'm trying to understand, I've completely removed everything related to that submodule, even from `.git/config/. Github knows that it has been removed, but it still shows the submodule as a grayed out folder

Comment: You should update your question with the exact Git commands you ran from the bash.  My guess is that the submodule is still part of your history.